# Which input/weight/bias dimensions have to match in order for a 2d transposed convolution to work?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to perform `torch.nn.functional.conv_transpose2d()` as part of my backward pass for my neural network, using an input of shape `[7, 4, 3, 7]`, weight of shape `[4, 2, 3, 3]` and a bias of shape `[4]`. My question is, are my dimensions ok and I just have an error somewhere in my code, or is this really not possible?

Additional info edit: The input is originally of shape `[7, 2, 5, 9]` but it goes through `torch.nn.functional.conv_2d()` in my forward pass, and becomes `[7, 4, 3, 7]`. I just realized this could also be causing the issue.

When I run the code using just `conv_transpose2d(input, weight, bias=bias)`, I get an error for the weight/bias dimension mismatch: `Given transposed=1, weight of size [4, 2, 3, 3], expected bias to be 1-dimensional with 2 elements, but got bias of size [4] instead`
I also tried using `weight.permute(1,0,2,3)` but but that gave an error for the weight/input dimension mismatch: `Given transposed=1, weight of size [2, 4, 3, 3], expected input[7, 4, 3, 7] to have 2 channels, but got 4 channels instead`

Does this mean that the dimensions are off, or am I just missing something simple like output padding?